# Does SQL NOT IN opeator scales good?

Tags: sql

I'm writing an app where users pass quizzes. So my purpose is to show quizzes which user didn't tackle before. For this reason I'm using `SELECT id, name, problem FROM quizzes WHERE id NOT IN (...)`.

Imagine that there will be thousands of ids and quizzes.

Is it ok? How does it scale? Probably I need to redesign something / using DB appropriate for that or use another technique to achieve my purpose?

Comment: Please post your query and your data structure, so we can help you. Add your used DBMS.

Comment: Olav, what is your database? Is it MS SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc.? Also, please specify its version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider there are limits to the SQL statements length imposed by each database engine. Though I haven't tested those limits, a 1k values in an `IN` operator should still work well for most databases, I would think that if you scale it up to 10k or more it could reach some databases limits and your statements will crash.

I would suggest rethinking this solution unless you can verify the worst possible case (with maximum parameters) still works well.

Usually a subquery can do the job, instead of manually sending 1k parameters or assembling a big SQL statement by concatenating strings.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed list, then it should be fine.

If you have a subquery, then I strongly encourage `not exists`:

```
from foo f
where not exists (select 1 from <bar> b where b.quiz_id = f.quiz_id)
```

I recommend this based on the *semantics* of `not exists` versus `not in`.  `not exists` handles `NULL` values more intuitively.

That said, with appropriate indexes, in most databases, `not exists` also often has the better performance.